# xcode 6 Swift Display shape on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, simulator

How can i get this circle to display on the Xcode 6 simulator using Swift?

```
//// Color Declarations
let color2 = UIColor(red: 0.000, green: 0.587, blue: 1.000, alpha: 1.000)

//// Oval Drawing
var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(92, 41, 38, 38))
color2.setFill()
ovalPath.fill()
UIColor.greenColor().setStroke()
ovalPath.lineWidth = 1
ovalPath.stroke()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put this code into the drawRect method of a custom UIView subclass. Then add a custom view to your storyboard scene, set it's class to your custom class and you're done.

Comment: I guess this is where I have gone wrong since I do not know how to crate a custom UIView subclass. Thank you.